how could i estimate free-field SPL from a small speaker driver, given measurements for in-ear conditions?
So, I'm reading this paper about a new piezoelectric MEMS speaker, designed for IEMs and such. Their results are super impressive and they give measurements for dB SPL, dB SPL/mm^2, dBSPL/mW. They describe their measurement setup with a specific ear simulator, but don't say how far they're measuring from. In the intro, they describe "typical" MEMS speakers of a different type having a certain SPL at 10 cm, but don't specify for the measurements they take for their own design.
I'm interested in ball-parking a free-field expected SPL if one made a huge array of these bad boys, since they're so power efficient. My understanding is free-field SPL measurements are taken referencing 1 m, so I could maybe scale it with inverse-square for the ~10x distance, assuming a similar measurement distance to those cited for other in-ear measurements. The problem is, I don't know how to account for the enclosure gain from their ear mockup.
Here's where I found the paper, Highly Miniaturized 115 Db Full-Range Mems Loudspeaker for In-Ear Applications: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4909768

this seems useful:
4.34  free-field equivalent earphone output level. At a given frequency, sound pressure level produced by the earphone in an acoustic coupler or ear simulator plus a correction consisting of the difference between the free-field sensitivity level and the coupler sensitivity level for the specified earphone. Unit, decibel (dB).
